# c++ what algorithm to use?

Tags: c++, algorithm, path

As input I receive the size of a rectangular graph (M * N), followed by the values of each node (P value and C value), followed by the cost of each node connection (first the horizontal costs and secondly the vertical ones).

when the input is:

```
5 5

8 7 9 9 7
6 2 2 8 7
9 1 2 1 8
2 1 3 1 7
1 3 2 1 9

2 1 2 3 2
1 9 9 1 3
1 7 7 9 3
8 7 9 7 2
7 9 8 9 1

8 9 7 6
1 9 0 8
1 8 9 2
8 7 9 1
9 8 7 2

8 2 1 7 9
7 8 7 1 8
2 8 7 7 8
9 7 8 9 8
```

I the output should be:

```
57

C C C C C
C P P C C
C P P P C
P P P P C
P P P P C
```

The output starts with the total cost of the graph (cost of C nodes + cost of P nodes + cost of C-P connections). A connection is only added to the total cost if it is vertical or horizontal (I dont want to add the diagonal ones).

My code at the moment is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct node {
  int pos;
  int plano;
  int cenario;
  /*true -> P, false -> C*/
  bool color;
} ;

std::vector<node> nodes;
int M, N;
int pesoTotal = 0;

void readInput()
{
    std::cin >> M;
    std::cin >> N;

    int total = M * N;

    for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
        int plano;
        node n;
        std::cin >> plano;

        n.pos=i+1;
        n.plano = plano;
        nodes.push_back(n);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
        int cenario;
        std::cin >> cenario;

        if(nodes[i].pos == i+1)
        {
            nodes[i].cenario = cenario;
            if(cenario <= nodes[i].plano)
        {
            nodes[i].color = false;
            pesoTotal += cenario;
        }
        else
        {
            nodes[i].color = true;
            pesoTotal += nodes[i].plano;
        }
    }
}

/*ligacoes horizontais*/
for(int i=0; i<M*N-1; i++)
{
    if(nodes[i].pos % N != 0)
    {
        int ligacao;
        std::cin >> ligacao;

        if(nodes[i].color != nodes[i+1].color)
        {
            pesoTotal += ligacao;
        }
    }
}

/*ligacoes verticais*/
for(int i=0; i<((M*N)-M); i++)
{
    int ligacao;
    std::cin >> ligacao;

    if(nodes[i].color != nodes[i+N].color)
    {
        pesoTotal += ligacao;
    }   
}
}

void imprimirOutput()
{
    std::cout << pesoTotal << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for(node n: nodes)
    {
        if(n.color == true)
        {
            std::cout << "P ";
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "C ";
        }

        if(n.pos % N == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    readInput();
    imprimirOutput();
}
```

This code accomplishes the example given above, my problem starts when the input gives me nodes where the P and C values are the same. In this case I need to minimize the cost and maximize the total of P values. This is where Im stuck.. Is there any knowen algorithm that can help me ? I did some research but could not find anything useful..

example:

input:

```
2 3

9 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 9

5 1
1 5

5 1 5
```

my output:

```
15

C P P 
P P P
```

correct output:

```
3

C C P
C P P
```

Comment: Where is problem statement? What are P and C?

Comment: A node has two values, P and C?  How is the total cost of the graph defined?

Comment: You did a good job of describing the input and output. What's missing is a description of the goal of the algorithm. What is the algorithm trying to accomplish? What are the rules the algorithm has to follow?